# how to fix 'No connected devices!' in last version (0.59) of react native?

Tags: android, react-native, sdk, genymotion

I installed last version ReactNative. When I run the project in android simulator ( Genymotion ), 'No connected devices!' error occurs.
how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using react-native run-android, then you must have a device to connect with system. You need to run into Genymotion through Android Studios. You can set genymotion as default using [Deepak's article](https://medium.com/@deepak.gulati/running-react-native-app-on-the-android-emulator-11bf309443eb).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the problem of SDK folder.